# Can I run the jetty-maven-plugin from within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, maven, m2eclipse

We're debugging java webapps, and would like to use the jetty-maven-plugin to launch a Jetty server. All of the documentation I have seen suggests that you should do it from the command line, which makes debugging and setting breakpoints in Eclipse difficult. Plus I'd like to see the output in the console window and be able to stop the process with red button. And do profiling as well.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you have m2eclipse installed then just enter in "jetty:run" as the goal you want to run.

You can however connect Eclipse's (or any IDE's) debugger to a running Jetty instance by launching [the jetty plugin with the JPDA flags](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Maven+Jetty+plugin#MavenJettyplugin-RunningthewebappindebugmodeusingJavaPlatformDebuggerArchitecture%28JPDA%29), without having to execute from within Eclipse.

Comment: Cool. That worked. I did Run As/Maven Build and filled in "jetty:run" as the goal. Do you know how to add that command to the Run As menu so I don't have to type it in each time?

Comment: Run Configurations > name of the specific config > Common tab > check box for "Display in favorites", or you can select the radio button for "Shared file" to save the launcher configuration as a file.

Comment: **Edit** Never mind: edit Run Configurations, click the Common tab, Display in favorites menu. It won't appear on Run As..., but it does appear under the green run button on the toolbar.